# How to adjust dropdown position in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to adjust my dropdown position because on my desktop and in mobile the dropdown not showing properly. It is showing half. Kindly check the image below:

[image: This is the problem. Dropdown showing half on desktop.]

[image: This is showing on mobile.]

Kindly check my code what I am doing:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" style="padding-top: 0.15rem"> <!-- style="padding-top: 2.8rem" -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Admin Panel</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">

   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">My Dashboard</a> <!-- style="color:#007bff;" -->
   </li>

  </ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <!-- Dropdown -->
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello rimi!</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-50px;">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="sp.php">My Profile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="cp.php">Change Password</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>

   </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

My problem is if I add margin-left:30px; then dropdown not visible on mobile. If I add padding-left:30px; same thing happen. In this case padding and margin not working. Also text link also not properly align. And not fixing by margin and padding.

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: I suspect your problem arises from a) your use of inline styles and b) this line of code here: `<div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-50px;">` which appears to be pulling your dropdown menu to the left as it is a negative margin. If you're able to show the relevant styles from your stylesheet, or provide a working demo, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Please overwrite bootstrap css in your css file.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: -90px;
}
```

Default is `left: 0;` in `Bootstrap.css` file. Add `negative` value what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the `style="margin-left:-50px;"` from your `dropdown-menu` class, and then change `ml-auto` to `mr-auto` (margin-left vs margin-right, which is where your menu is defaulting).

Here's a **[codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/pQWpRE)** if that works better for you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" style="padding-top: 0.15rem"> <!-- style="padding-top: 2.8rem" -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Admin Panel</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">

   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">My Dashboard</a> <!-- style="color:#007bff;" -->
   </li>

  </ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <!-- Dropdown -->
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello rimi!</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-50px;">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="sp.php">My Profile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="cp.php">Change Password</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>

   </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
```